# Calculate school year from date of birth in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to calculate a school year from date of birth and would like `SharePoint` to update as and when necessary.
I know this is possible in Excel but wondered if there was a work around for `Now` or `Today` in `SharePoint`.
The code I am using is:

```
=IF([Date of Birth]="","","Year "&MAX(0,DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR([Date of Birth]+122),9,1),NOW(),"Y" )-4))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sample forum to get year count between dates.

```
=VALUE(TEXT(NOW(),"yyyy"))-VALUE(TEXT([Date of Birth],"yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

> if there was a work around for Now or Today in SharePoint.

Not by just using a Calculated Column. A Calculated column is only updated with the item is created or edited.

You can add JavaScript to the page to update the displayed school year each time a page loads, but you would need to add this to each of the list's forms and Views. The exact JavaScript solution depends on your SharePoint version. Can you update your question with the version? (2010, 2013, 2016, SharePoint Online - classic UI, SharePoint Online modern UI, etc.)